# What is the meaning of 'baize over a budgerigar'?

Tags: harry-potter, languages

> *" - And we wait," Ron finished, throwing it over Hermione's head like baize over a budgerigar and rolling his eyes at Harry."*
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*: Chapter 12</sub>

**What is the meaning of “*baize over a budgerigar*”?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure the quote is *"over Hermione's head like baize on a budgerigar and rolling his eyes at Harry."*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think it is a simile likening Ron's act to the act of throwing a cloth cover over a bird cage, [as one does at night](https://www.thesprucepets.com/should-birdcage-be-covered-at-night-390338). ["Budgerigar" or "budgie"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgerigar) is the common name in British English for a bird known as a "parakeet" in American English, and [baize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baize) is a type of heavy cloth, most commonly known as the surface on snooker and casino tables.

In the American version, that line is:

> throwing it over Hermoine's head like a blanket over a birdcage

In any case, the visual is a cloth draped over some substantial structure—a bird cage, or Hermione!

Comment: @IMSoP I think I have a decent vocabulary and I’ve never heard of that **or** a budgerigar. I agree with the editor.

Comment: [Billy the Kid and the Green Baize Vampire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088807/). I thought it was if not everyday usage, then common enough. @ToddWilcox

Comment: @JiminyCricket. It might be known among snooker players, but snooker itself isn't *that* popular in the US. (I know of it, but know very little *about* it.)

Comment: Pool is played on the same surface, I guess it has a different name there. @chepner

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Typically just referred to as *felt*, as far as I know.

Comment: @chepner Exactly. Or *the felt* or *green*, as in “there’s a lot of green on that shot”, meaning it’s a long distance from the cue ball to the object ball. I’ve played extensively among APA members and read several books and never came across “baize” in relation to American pocket billiards AKA pool.

Comment: TIL that Americans don't know what a budgie is. Admittedly, I've never heard an American use that term on TV or movies, but it's kind of hard to notice the words that people *don't* use.

Comment: To my UK ears, hearing the word baize brings two pictures to mind - a snooker table, or the soundproofed door between the servant's quarters and the rest of a posh house.

Comment: @PM2Ring I knew it was a small bird, but I didn't know it was the same as a parakeet.

Comment: I think it's an unusual word choice because it's alliteration. But also, the reason you "cover a budgie" is sometimes to get it to shut up. A (close weave? felt?) blanket will help it keep warm at night(it used to be standard practice in the UK) but it can also trick the budgie into thinking it's night and it should be quiet. So the phrase also conveys some meaning about Ron's intentions.

Comment: interestingly the word "parakeet" is also used in the UK, just for different species (primarily the rose-ringed parakeet which has a large feral population in London) tha  the common parakeet

Comment: baize is also not the same as felt, as it is woven rather than felted (matting unspun fibres), although it often has a similar texture. Snooker tends to use baize with significant nap affecting the behaviour of the ball significantly, whereas pool tends to use baize without much nap so the balls can roll more freely

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Wait until you find out what a "budgie smuggler" is then .. hint: it has nothing to do with budgies or smuggling .. lol

Comment: @PeterM I believe we refer to it as a banana hammock.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm an American and I know what a budgie is, but I read a lot and Terry Pratchett is my favorite author, so I couldn't tell you how common that is.

Comment: I’m American and also read a lot of Pratchett, but had no idea what a budgie was. Makes me wonder how much I’ve been missing from his books.